# Weird issue with a program that checks if a 2D matrix is symmetric

Tags: c

I'm currently working on a program that tests whether a 2D matrix is symmetric. Code:

```
int IsSym (int ** rels, int universe)
{  
int ii,  jj;
for ( ii = 1; ii < universe; ii++)
    {
        for ( jj = ii; jj < universe; jj++)
      {
          if (rels[ii][jj] != rels[jj][ii])
          {
          return 0;
          }
      }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Now this code will only have to search half the matrix to determine if symmetric. It does this by just simply checking if the one sides value equals the other sides value. However, it appears to not always be working. For example if I go to input data as such

```
1 1
2 2
```

Will work as expected and say it is symmetric. However

```
1 1
2 2
2 1
```

Will not. The issue appears to have something to do with the row value being inputted as higher than the column value.

Now I know I can fix this simple by just going through the entire matrix and checking. But I am more curious as to why having it set up like this is not working?

Comment: `for ( ii = 1; ii < universe; ii++)` Hmm... Index is normally from zero. Not one.

Comment: That is a very weird equality check.  Use the much simpler (and correct): `if (rels[ii][jj] != rels[jj][ii])`

Comment: Yeah i forgot to mention that the indexing at 0 is used for something else. the 1 still corresponds to the correct matrix value.

Comment: `if (rels[ii][jj] && !rels[jj][ii])` did you mean `if (rels[ii][jj] != rels[jj][ii])`

Comment: Whoops yes i fixed it. The other way still worked.

Comment: @BunBuns No, not fixed. You still have one `!` too many

Comment: Your definition of "symmetric" seems strange. None of your examples seems symmetric to me. How can a 3x2 matrix be symmetric? Do you really mean "identical columns"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue lies here, you are using an extra `!` with matrix elements:

```
if (rels[ii][jj] != !rels[jj][ii])
{
    return 0;
}
```

It should be:

```
if (rels[ii][jj] != rels[jj][ii])
    return 0;
```

`!` of any non-zero number gives `0` else `1`. See the following code for the explanation:

```
int a[2][2] = {{1,2}, {0,0}};
    for(size_t i=0;i<2;i++)
        for(size_t j=0;j<2;j++)
            printf("%d ",!a[i][j]);
    return 0;
```

The output will be:

```
0 0 1 1
```

Comment: :-)  i will delete my answer

Comment: happ to help :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that your code expects a matrix with the same number of columns and rows, i.e a `universe` by `universe` matrix.

So there is no way this code can work with a 3x2 matrix.

In general the term "symmetric" seem to make little sense for 3x2 matrix.

BTW: In C the index normally starts from zero - not one. But OP commented that it's on purpose.

Answer (score 0):

A **symmetric** matrix is a **square** matrix that is equal to its transpose. Only square matrix can be checked to be a symmetric matrix. You don't care about diagonal elements to be equal because they are always equal.So, column always be started with `ii + 1`

```
int IsSym (int ** rels, int universe)
{  
int ii,  jj;
for ( ii = 1; ii < universe; ii++)
    {
        for ( jj = ii + 1; jj < universe; jj++)
      {
          if (rels[ii][jj] != rels[jj][ii])
          {
          return 0;
          }
      }
    }
    return 1;
}
```